# ¿Cómo reemplazar operador lógico "o" (|) en un string en r?

Tags: r, string, regex

Tengo una serie de strings con valores separados por ||, a los cuales necesitaría reemplazar por una coma.

```
a_separar <- c("A||B","A||B||C", "B||C")
```

pero al intentar hacerlo con gsub, tengo dificultades en lo que creo es escapar una expresión regular:

```
gsub("\\||", ",", a_separar)
```

El resultado obtenido es:

```
[1] ",A,,B,"    ",A,,B,,C," ",B,,C,"
```

cuando lo deseado sería:

```
[1] "A,B"    "A,B,C" "B,C"
```

¿Qué error estoy cometiendo, y cómo podría llegar al resultado deseado? Gracias!

Comment: Solo te falta escapar el segundo `|`. Debería de ser 
`gsub("\\|\\|", ",", a_separar)`

Comment: @césarhuamanininahuanca perfecto, muchas gracias! No me había dado cuenta que tenía que considerar a cada | por separado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución sencilla sería incorporar el argumento `fixed`:

```
gsub("||", ",", a_separar, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "A,B"   "A,B,C" "B,C"
```

Answer (score -4):

En R, se pueden utilizar expresiones regulares para buscar y manipular patrones específicos de texto. Así mismo, existen caracteres especiales para usarlos en estas expreciones.

- **\**: este carácter se utiliza para escapar otros caracteres especiales.

El carácter "|" tiene un significado en las expresiones regulares, por lo cual debes usar cuatro bachslashes para escapar correctamente el caracter "|".

Por lo tanto, la expresión correcta para obtener el resultado deseado sería:

```
gsub("\\\\|", ",", a_separar)
```

Esto reemplazará todas las instancias del caracter "|" por una coma "," en cada elemento de la lista a_separar.

El resultado obtenido sería:

```
[1] "A,B"    "A,B,C"  "B,C"
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa este [artículo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido).

Comment: El resultado que obtengo de esa manera en realidad es ",A,|,|,B,"  ",A,|,|,B,|,|,C," ",B,|,|,C,"

Comment: ¿Lo probaste? ¿o simplemente copiaste la respuesta de ChatGPT? por que definitivamente no funciona. Por otro lado, la respuesta ya está en uno de los comentarios y la solución es tan simple que no agregamos mucho valor al sitio respondiéndola.

Comment: Puedes entrar a Chat gpt y pregunta "recuerdas esta respuesta"? y te indicará si la ha generado antes o no.

Comment: @JoseLuisCastillaMedina Si no sabes del tema, evita responder, saludos.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.